# Why wp_update_post strip slashes?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to update the post_content:

```
<?php 
$something = '<a class=\"class_name\" href=\"#\">';
$my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 1,
      'post_content' => $something,
  );
  wp_update_post( $my_post );
?>
```

Could anyone tell me why this always strips slashes from the $something? 
What can I do to avoid this situation and update it just as it's in $something?

Comment: How have you confirmed it's removing backslashes, and why are you trying to put backslashes in that fashion?

Answer (score 0):

@miken32
I've looked into database and it's stripped there :-) I need this because I want to update data that's been stored by another plugin which needs specifically this format in order to work properly.

I already fixed this by replacing wp_update_post with wpdb->update. It seems that this one updates exactly as I wanted.